# How to split a CSV file depending of row values

Tags: file, powershell, csv, split

Below is only an example, I have seen a lot of script to breakdown a .CSV file in smaller files but struggling with this.

How can we with PowerShell, find the header indicated by ALPH take each subsequent line, stop when it reaches ALPT (inclusive) and put this text into another file. 
The operation will need to run through the whole file and the number of ALPD or ALPC lines will vary.

ALPH can be considered as a header while the information contained is needed as some field value can be different. The only constant are ALPH and ALPT.

```
ALPH;8102014
ALPC;PK
ALPD;50
ALPD;40
ALPT;5
ALPH;15102014
ALPC;PK
ALPD;50
ALPD;50
ALPD;70
ALPD;70
ALPD;71
ALPD;72
ALPD;40
ALPT;6
ALPH;15102014
ALPC;PK
ALPD;50
ALPD;50
ALPD;40
ALPT;6
```

Comment: Do you need the number after 'ALPH;'?

Comment: It would be the complete line each time.
For example:
ALPH,08102014
ALPC,PK
ALPD,50
ALPD,40
ALPT,5

However JPBlanc provided a working script - thanks

I will test with more data and return if I found any issues
THanks

Comment: Yeah, I found a really quick way with -split, but it omitted the ALPH;* line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using switch. Your original file is in `C:\temp\ALPH.CSV` here is the way I imagine to find the begin an the end.

```
$n = 1
switch -File 'C:\temp\ALPH.CSV' -Regex
{
  '^ALPH.*' {
    Write-Host "Begin $n"
  }
  '^ALPT.*' {
    Write-Host "End $n"
    $n++
  }
}
```

Now saving lines to a var and exporting files :

```
$n = 1
$csvTmp = @()
switch -File 'C:\temp\ALPH.CSV' -Regex
{
  '^ALPH.*' {
    Write-Host "Begin $n"
    $csvTmp += $_
  }
  '^ALPT.*' {
    Write-Host "End $n"
    $csvTmp += $_
    $csvTmp | Set-Content "c:\temp\file$n.csv"
    $csvTmp = @()
    $n++
  }
  default {
    $csvTmp += $_
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, something like this should work:

```
$csv     = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
$pattern = 'ALPH[\s\S]*?ALPT.*'
$cnt     = 0

[IO.File]::ReadAllText($csv) | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches |
  select -Expand Matches | select -Expand Groups | 
  % {
    $cnt++
    $outfile = Join-Path (Split-Path $csv -Parent) "split${cnt}.csv"
    [IO.File]::WriteAllText($outfile, $_.Value)
  }
```